# Delete data from mongoose using checkbox (Node JS w/ AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete data from Mongo DB (mongoose in this case) using Node JS (w/ Express), and JQuery AJAX.

So, there are checkboxes with a data near them (interface). When I check one or more of these checkboxes, and then press SUBMIT, I want them to be deleted from database (Mongo DB).

Thus, I tried using DELETE request, getting data from AJAX, and then removing it from DB (using Model.remove() ), but as soon as I want to get req.params (in order to remove item from db), I do get only 'undefined'. I think something is wrong with my Ajax, but not sure what exactly.

### Express

```
    app.delete('/index', function(req,res){

    console.log("req body: " + req.body); // Undefined?
    console.log(req.params.del); // Undefined as well
    console.log(req.params.data); // Undefined as well

    Blog.remove({item: req.params.del}, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

### AJAX

```
    $('#deleteAcc').on('click', function(){
      //var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
      var item = $(".checkbox input:checked").parent();
      item.remove();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/index',
        del: item,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  });
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple blogging website</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/appAJAX.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center" size="40px">Welcome to blog!</h1>
    <h2 align="center" size="36px">Best UX/UI Website ever!</h2>
    <form style="text-align: center;">
        <input style="width: 400px; height: 125px;" type="text" name="inputText" placeholder="Piss someone off..." required/>
        <button type="submit">Submit post</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="control-group">
        <% for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" /><%= posts[i].item %>
        </label>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button type="button" id="deleteAcc">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you try the sintaxe `data: {del: item}` instead of `del: item`?

Comment: @ElmerDantas Nothing happens to DB data. It firstly removes, but when I refresh web page, it remains the same.

Comment: you're missing some html details do make the ajax request...you're not passing the value to the server...because of that, you're getting undefined...I'm at work but I'm try to write some piece of code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've made [this fiddleJS](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pao95k9v/4/)...change some things to be as you want...the checkbox's value will be something like `posts[i].item._id` assuming the `item` object has an ID (should have)  and then you'll probably be able to access in your server `req.body.deletedItems`

Hope it helps

Comment: So, I changed this, but now it deletes everything, whether I checked the box or not.

Blog.remove({item: req.params.deletedItems}, function(err, data){  
            if (err) throw err;  
            res.json(data);  
});

Comment: you need to iterate through the array to delete each item from your collection...only after this, return to client whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for writing my notice as an answer, I don't have enough points to write comments. But relating to @ElmerDantas answer you pass an array of ids to your back-end. So you will have to iterate through the array using for loop and inside your for loop you try to delete "selected" objects with mongoose remove method:

Try to do something like this:

```
var ids = req.params.deletedItems;
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
 Blog.remove({item: ids[i]}, function(err, data){ if (err) throw err; res.json(data); })}
```

Comment: Like this? Using EJS, template library
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f80e737fd01c652c8fe3238b82b270d9

Comment: With Elmer's solution you already get all your ids into array which you pass to your back-end. And my solution is for your back-end

Comment: It says that req.params.deletedItems is undefined and cannot read property length (i.e. at loop condition " i < ids.length; " )

Here is screenshot: http://prntscr.com/dxn5y1

Comment: Hmmm, that means your router doesn't get the deletedItems array which is strange. Try to console output the array and check your ajax syntax

Comment: It is either undefined or empty object. However, it is interesting that Ajax processes it and array is not empty (i.e., it's working), but it cannot transfer to app.delete() request (probably, because of problems with index? because I have universal url='index' )

Comment: try to get your array from body object on your back-end. use req.body.deletedItems instead of req.params

Comment: `req.params` is used when you pass a querystring to a post/put/delete method. e.g `/api/users?test=value` on the server you retrieve this value using `req.params.test` for submit/ajax submit you retrieve the value using `req.body` which is in your case `req.body.deletedItems`

Comment: I tried with `req.body`, but I still get `undefined` . I think the problem is either how to get needed data (deletedItems) from Ajax, or I may be wrongly using body-parser. Screenshot is here: http://prntscr.com/dyb0l8

Comment: Hum...I see. That's something missing...maybe the `body-parser`...change it the `DELETE` for `POST` in your ajax call and see if it work. Also, try to understand better how the ajax delete works...you have everything you need, now make it work altogether. Sorry for cannot help any further...I do not have an enviroment to test requests for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain id or value for each checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<%= posts[i]._id"/><%= posts[i].item %>
```

incorrect syntax in ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#deleteAcc').on('click', function(){
  var item = new Array();
    if($('input:checkbox:checked').length>0){
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        item.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });
      sendResponse(item);
    }
 });
  function sendResponse(item) {
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"/index",
      data:{item:item},
      success:function(data){
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Make a post request in controller; 
req.body is an object not array, so you can only access by key;
use $in as comparison query operator for removing documents in collection

```
app.post('/index', function(req,res){
    var items=[];
    for(var key in req.body){
        items=req.body[key];
    }
    Blog.remove({_id:{$in:items}},function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Hope this Helps !! :)